# Angularjs highcharts and modal windows clear previous chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am displaying a chart in modal window with angularjs and highcharts. It is working fine the only problem is it won't clear a old chart on modal closing, here is my code

```
reportModule.directive('hcChart', function () {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(function () { return attrs.chart; }, function () {

                if (!attrs.chart) return;

                var charts = JSON.parse(attrs.chart);

                $(element[0]).highcharts(charts);

            });
        }
    };
});
```

and my data

```
$scope.chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Title'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories:  ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: yText,
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Year 2016',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            }],
             plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                shadow: true
            },
            loading: true
    };
```

and html

```
<hc-chart chart='{{ chartOptions }}'>Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>
```

Here what I tried

```
$('#report').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.chartOptions=null;
      });
    })
```

but it is not working. I just want to clear old chart values on modal close please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to set the chartOptions as an empty instead of null. Since you set it to null, there will be an error on JS to not execute anymore.

```
$('#report').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.chartOptions={};
  });
})
```

---

**Update: Removes the chart and purges memory. This method should be called before writing a new chart into the same container. It is called internally on window unload to prevent leaks.**

1. Add the id for chart element

`<hc-chart id="highChart" chart='{{ chartOptions }}'>Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>`

2. Update your code

`$('#report').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $timeout(function(){
        $('#highChart').highcharts().destroy();
      });
    })`

Comment: I forget to mention that I already tried that but this will display empty chart on opening modal. I want to completely destroy the chart and refresh the modal

Comment: I know the chart will be displayed as a blank chart with a white background if we set the chartOptions to be an empty object. So what is your expected behavior after clear the chart, and next time when you open the modal ?
Normally when the user clicks on another button to open the modal, it should display a different chart or same chart but different data.

Comment: exactly, any idea how to completely destroy $scope.chartOptions or do i need to destroy directive

Comment: I just want to display blank modal.

Comment: your above code will remove highchart div it means i will not able to view other graph is there anyway to refresh the div??

Comment: Oh, I see. Just check my update question. I based on the destroy function of highcharts http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.destroy

Comment: Glad to hear it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the series :

```
$scope.chartOptions.series[0].remove(true);
```

Comment: i tried but error  $scope.chartOptions.series[0].remove is not a function